# Webkit in iOS, does it works?

Tags: iphone, webkit

Does the webkit is able to create an iPhone application like ? and if it is do you have some link that explain how to use it ?

Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? (Also, "does the iOS can use" is very unclear, consider using http://translate.google.com to help.)

Comment: Please flag this for moderator attention to re-open once you've added quite a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand you question. Do you want to run a webapplication natively. Then you can do so by having just a UIWebView in the whole application which loads the web content.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. Do you mean a Web application? If so, check [Safari Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action).